# How to display an external website in a webform?

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm new at webforms, trying to change from winforms, so this I'm posing this basic question. If I have a button that when clicked redirects to another webpage within a site master project, how do I simply display an external website in the content place holder of the project?

If when the button is pressed, a response.redirect statement is issued to another webform where I want "http://www.google.com" to be displayed in the content place holder.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use iframe in redirected page 

add the iframe to page 
<iframe name="myIframe" id="myIframe" width="400px" height="400px" runat =server></iframe>

in page load event set iframe src attribute to load the external website

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myIframe.Attributes.Add("src", "http://www.google.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using html control you can easily redirect from page 1 to page 2

```
Add below line into Page1.aspx

<a href="Page2.aspx">Google site</a>

Add below Iframe into Page2.aspx 

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 500px; border:none;" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```